# R: used `which` statement with multiple conditions = how to treat result?

Tags: r

Hey I am new to R and I would like to find out, which **city** has the highest T AND the highest SO2-value.
The dataset is data("USairpollution").

First I asked:

```
max(x$SO2)
rownames(x)[which(x$SO2>=110)]
max(x$temp)
rownames(x)[which(x$temp>=75.5)]
```

combined it after long trial and error to:

```
maxT_maxSO2=(which(x == max(x$SO2)) & (x == max(x$temp)))
```

Now, my question is: I have now a dataframe with one single TRUE.

1. is this the correct city?
2. how can I find out the name? (Apart from visually checking the dataframe)

Comment: The maximum of `SO2` and the maximum of `temp` are present in two different cities. What is your expected outcome?

Comment: What about `which(x$SO2 == max(x$SO2) & x$temp == max(x$temp))`?

Answer (score 0):

After executing folloing command:

```
  x <- x[order(x$SO2, decreasing=T),]
```

Result:
On the first line of your matrix you will have the max. SO2, which is Chicago. 
If you wanted find a Maximum of both variable, maybe it would be helpful to sum the SO2 and temp and than search for maxima.